# Xamarin.iOS Object Losing Property Members

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms project with UWP, Android and iOS. I use a SQL Database hosted in Azure on the back end and a user can search for foods and get the different measures and nutrient values that go with the food. The issue is that I use a foreach loop to loop through a list of the queried foods and create and object to hold the higher level food properties (like name and measure) and combine a second list that contains all the nutrients and nutrient values for that food. In the process of creating the object, only on iOS, the Measure property is not getting set when there is data in the looping object and in debugging mode I see the value for Measure as {...} and the property Measure acutally disappears from the instantiated object. This only happens on iOS, not UWP or Android. Here is a picture of it in debugging:
[Food item with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj8H6.png)
Here is the new object instantiated missing properties:
[NewFood without some properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z3L9.png)
Here is the Measure property with something I have never seen:
[Measure Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2McDD.png)

Here is the food object class

```cs
public class FoodNutrients : BindableObject
    {
        public string NDB { get; set; }
        public string Food { get; set; }
        public string Measure { get; set; }
        public string MeasureType { get; set; }
        public string MeasureAmount { get; set; }
        public double Protein { get; set; }
        public double Sodium { get; set; }
        public double Potassium { get; set; }
        public double Phosphorus { get; set; }
        public double Carbs { get; set; }
        public double Fat { get; set; }
        public double SaturatedFat { get; set; }
        public double Calories { get; set; }
        public string SodiumRec { get; set; }
        public string ProteinRec { get; set; }
        public string PotassiumRec { get; set; }
        public string PhosphorusRec { get; set; }
        public string CarbsRec { get; set; }
        public string FatRec { get; set; }
        public string SatFatRec { get; set; }
        public string CaloriesRec { get; set; }
        public string Recommendation { get; set; }
        public string RecColor { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the foreach loop

```cs
foreach (var food in foodList1)
                {
                    FoodNutrients newFood = new FoodNutrients();
                    string measureString = "- " + food.MeasureAmount + " " + food.Measure;
                    newFood.NDB = food.NDB;
                    newFood.Food = food.Food;
                    newFood.MeasureType = food.Measure;
                    newFood.MeasureAmount = food.MeasureAmount;
                    newFood.Measure = measureString;
                    newFood.Protein = FoodNutrients.GetProteinValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Sodium = FoodNutrients.GetSodiumValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Potassium = FoodNutrients.GetPotassiumValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Phosphorus = FoodNutrients.GetPhosphorusValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Carbs = FoodNutrients.GetCarbValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Fat = FoodNutrients.GetFatValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.SaturatedFat = FoodNutrients.GetSatFatValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood.Calories = FoodNutrients.GetCalorieValue(foodList2, food.NDB, (double)food.MeasureWeightGrams);
                    newFood = DailyAllowanceController.GetRecommendation(newFood, user);
                    foodList.Add(newFood);
                }
```

Again, there are no syntax errors and this code words perfectly in Android and UWP. Please look at the images in the above description as they provide some real details.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to set the Linker in the iOS Build settings Link SDK assemblies only. Then save and rebuild and redeploy and that fixed my issue. Very confusing.